# Counting vowels and Consonants in a SubString

Tags: python

Having some troubles with finding and counting all possible substrings which begin either with Vowels or Consonants, and print the number of them in the output, some ideas?

````
word = input() 

# defining vowels
vowels = "aeiou"

count_v = 0
count_c = 0

word.lower()

for i in range(len(word)):
    for j in range(i, len(word)):
        for k in range(i, (j + 1)):
            print(word[k], end="")
        print()

print(f"number of substrings starting with Vowels: {count_v} - number of substrings starting with Consonants: {count_c} ```
````

Comment: What's the problem and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: `word.lower()` doesn't do anything. Strings are immutable, so this returns a new string. You need to assign that to a variable.

Comment: I don't have any idea how to extract the output from the substring loop and then count vowels and Consonants.

Comment: You don't need to test all substrings. If the string is `abcde`, and the current index is the first letter, there are 5 substrings starting from there, and they all start with the same letter, which is a vowel. So just add 5 to the vowel count. On the next iteration you add 4 to the consonant count.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to use a list and get its length :

```
 Count_v = len([e for e in words.split(" ") if e[0].lower() in vowels])
```

I let you do the opposite for consonants.

Comment: The question says substrings, not words.

Comment: Could you give me an example of a string and the substrings extracted from it?

Comment: `string = "abcde"` Substrings are `a`, `ab`, `abc`, `abcd`, `abcde`, `b`, `bc`, `bcd`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate()` to get the letter and index together, rather than using `range(len(word))`.

You don't need a nested loop, because all the substrings starting at a particular index start with the same letter. And starting at a particular index, there are `len(word) - index` substrings.

If the letter isn't a vowel, you should check that it's alphabetic to determine if it's a consonant, in case the user enters characters that aren't alphabet.

```
for i, letter in enumerate(word.lower()):
    if letter in vowels:
        count_v += len(word) - i
    elif letter.isalpha():
        count_c += len(word) - i
```